# Difficulties with Cypress scrollTo method

Tags: cypress

I am having a few issues testing a virtual scroll component with Cypress. I have a test that checks the li elements present in the DOM after scrolling to the bottom of a container.

When written like this the test passes:

```
cy.get('.virtual-scroll').scrollTo('bottom')
cy.wait(0)                                             
cy.get('li').last().children('h4').contains('1999')
```

When written like this it doesn't:

```
cy.get('.virtual-scroll').scrollTo('bottom')
cy.get('li').last().children('h4').contains('1999')
```

This also fails:

```
cy.get('.virtual-scroll').scrollTo('bottom').get('li').last().children('h4').contains('1999')
```

In the second and third examples, get('li') is returning the li elements present before the scroll has completed, and therefore failing the test. I can fix this by adding .wait, but don't fully understand the behaviour and wonder if this is a bug.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make an assertion that will always pass when the `DOM` is rendered, such as using `.get()` for an element that gets added to the `DOM`

ex) if you had a `<ul class="myloadedlist">....` :

```
cy.get('.virtual-scroll').scrollTo('bottom')
cy.get('ul.myloadedlist')
cy.get('li').last().children('h4').contains('1999')
```

That way, Cypress will continue with the test as soon as that element becomes visible.

#### Why?

I'm assuming the elements get added to the `DOM` in some sort of scroll `eventListener`. In that case this is *correct* behavior.

Essentially what you've tested is the **race condition** of a user scrolling *very quickly* to the bottom of the page, to see that the `DOM` has not yet finished rendering- a valid senario.

Since you targeted the `last()` `li` element, Cypress finds the last element of the page ***before* the `DOM` gets updated**, and expects it to `contain` `1999`, which it does not, even after Cypress retries for 4 seconds.

This is actually a great feature of Cypress, because you can test on the state of the `DOM` at times that the User might only see for a *split second*.

Comment: `cy.scrollTo('bottom')` and `cy.wait(500)` did the trick for the race condition and smooth scroll. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding a duration to the scroll option did the trick.
`cy.get("@dialogContent").scrollTo("center", { duration: 500 });`